# Idioms of use/ bitcoin heuristic

Tags: blockchain, currencies, cryptography

[image: Question]

I already know the answer of a) part which is Alice. Can anybody help me in finding answer of b) part.

Comment: What information are we to assumer 'the observer' has? Do they know the A/B/C tagged addresses are controlled by A/B/C? Do they know for *certain* which addresses are change addresses? In general, 'certainty' of blockchain analysis is a somewhat hopeless goal in the real world.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where does this question come from ? It's, strangely, identical to one of the HWs in one of my classes.